# Edit existing directory in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

This might be a dumb question, but I have a project I am trying to edit a few files for and using eclipse 4.20.0 as an IDE.

When I try to import the directory in eclipse, it creates a completely separate eclipse workspace directory and stores the files in there for my editing. (When I make changes, files in the eclipse workspace directory are changed, but not the original directory)

Is there a way to open the original directory in Eclipse and edit files directly in there? Or am I going to have to work inside the directory eclipse created and then manually move the files over every time to test them again?

I swear I've done this before, but it's been a few years so I might just be importing the directory wrong.

Comment: Probably you used _File > Import...: General > Existing Projects into Workspace_ with the option _Copy projects into workspace_. Don't use this option if you don't want it. Or better use _File > Open Projects from File System..._.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only making a couple changes, just clicking on the .java class you need in your explorer and "Open With... -> Eclipse IDE" will allow you to edit the specific file without opening up a new project. If you are trying to open the project and work on all the files at once, *File > Open Projects from File System* usually works pretty well on eclipse. If you are opening another eclipse project, just click on the folder where the .project is stored when opening, not necessarily clicking into the folder itself.